# Is it correct the example of the matrix determinant in the English wikipedia

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Because I wanted to know the meaning and formula of the determinant of matrices,

I referred to the English Wikipedia over the concept.

In Wikipedia, the concept and meaning of the determinant were suggested in the terms of the column vectors as below.

[image]

But in the definition section, the descriptions were suggested by using the below two depicts.

[image]

[image]

In this case, I had one question.

Although the first description used the concept of the column vector,

Why did the definition example use the row vector concept suddenly?

Of course, I understood the description using the row vector concept to prove the formula, (i.e., (a, b), and (c, d))

and I checked the column vector concept also could prove the formula.

But I don't know why the approach was changed from column vector to row vector.

Why is the vector concept not consistent?

Comment: It is probably because the article has several authors, some of which prefer row-vectors to column-vectors. There is nothing about determinants that requires us to switch from one to the other.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, the determinant of a square matrix $A$ is equivalent to the determiannt of the transpose of $A$, so in other words, $\det [A] = \det [A^T]$. In general, if we take the transpose of a matrix, the columns become the rows and the rows become the columns. So, whether the columns or rows are used for computing the determinant doesn't matter.

So, for a $2 \times 2$ matrix, this can be seen as follows:

$$
\begin{align}
 \det A = \det \begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix} = ad - bc
\end{align}
$$

and

$$
\begin{align}
 \det A = \det \begin{bmatrix} a & c \\ b & d \end{bmatrix} = ad - bc
\end{align}
$$

You can work this out for larger matrices, but in general, this is true for all square matrices.

Now, why the approached was changed between example, I do not know, but as @BenGrossmann mentioned in the comments, the article has several authors, which is likely the only reason.